# A *special* sequence of dots and lines (from first to last)

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, sequence

**What you see here is a complete sequence of dots and lines. Can you tell me what this sequence represents?**

---

[image]

Comment: No knowledge required other than trivial. This is a sequence that will make sense once you figure out what it's all about.

Comment: looks a lot like rot13(Raarntenz bs Crefbanyvgl), but I can't position the lines to match this one. Am I on the right track?

Comment: @Lezzup No, not on the right track. That would be specified knowledge. This is based on something you don't really need google for.

Comment: I'm planning to give you a hint soon. If someone has kinda made sense of it, let me know, I might wait then.

Comment: Wait, don't add the hint yet ... `;)`

Comment: @MOehm Alright, I'll wait then

Comment: Thanks. I'm sure your patience will be rewarded ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The sequence represents ...

> ... the first nine **prime numbers**.

How so?

> The prime numbers are shown as **full hours** on a 12-hour **analog clock**, so that 5 is 05:00 am and 17 is 05:00 pm. The black dot is the centre of the clock face. The red line connects the tips of the hour and minute hands, which are not shown. The minute hand is always at the full hour position. The hour hand is about half as long as the minute hand.
>
>  [image: 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23]

Comment: A man of his word :) Great solve! rot13(Ol pbzcyrgr frdhrapr V whfg zrnag gurfr ner nyy gur shyy ubhe "cevzr gvzrf" (gjb gb gjragl-guerr) ab fhpu gvzr nf gjragl-avar, guvegl-bar rgp...)